# How to add the green plus button on a models.ForeignKey field?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, admin

I've got a field such as this one in my models.py:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey('masters.Master', blank=True, null=True, db_index=True, related_name='master_of')
```

But in the Django admin there is not the little green "+" button at the right so you can't add a new master from there, which is not very practical.

So I'd like the green "+" button to appear on the "master" field in order to be able to directly add a master from there.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try that: http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/

Comment: There must be a lot easier way to do it, because before it worked but I changed some things and now I just realized that the plus button disappeared.

Comment: The plus + is added to all foreign key but it's based on the permissions the user has on that model, are you sure you have the correct permissions? Make sure the related model is also registered for the admin.

Comment: Yes I can add a new master from the appropriate form from the admin.

Answer (score 6):

Is your Master model registered in you admin.py?

If not, Django will not handle it.

Comment: Sure it is registered and handled.

Comment: Can you paste your admin.py for the "masters" app?

Comment: Actually I just realize I usa a forms.ModelChoiceField for the field master and when I take it away it works! But I need to use it though. So how can I ask forms.ModelChoiceField to use the green "+" button?

Comment: It should be possible by extending the default widget or by modifying the template. Another (cleaner) solution would be to keep the default field definitions/widgets for the form and just override the queryset for this FK in your admin.py. See: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1558/#c4674

Comment: double-check if the model is registered